# Swift 2.0 and CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback via @convention(c)

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-graphics, core-animation, core-video

Has anyone managed to use CVDisplayLink timer without bridging the Objective-C code?

with the addition of @convention(c) , it should be possible but I still get segmentation error : 11 when trying to use CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback

```
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)


    CVDisplayLinkCreateWithActiveCGDisplays(&displayLink)
    CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(displayLink!, callback,  UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(unsafeAddressOf(self!)) )
}
//call back declarations
let callback : @convention(c)(displayLink: CVDisplayLink, inNow: UnsafePointer<CVTimeStamp>, inOutputTime: UnsafePointer<CVTimeStamp>, flagsIn: CVOptionFlags, flagsOut: UnsafeMutablePointer<CVOptionFlags>, displayLinkContext: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> CVReturn =
{ (displayLink, inNow, inOutputTime, flagsIn, flagsOut, displayLinkContext) -> CVReturn in
    let context = UnsafeMutablePointer<GraphView>(displayLinkContext)
    let newContext = context.memory
    let error = newContext.getFrameForTime(inOutputTime)

    return error;
    return kCVReturnSuccess
}
```

is it now possible for me to do so? or Bridging is still necessary to achieve Precision timer?

Comment: I got this code to work in swift. Im not sure if it has any c-bridging yet. https://github.com/steven741/basic-opengl-swift/blob/45179a646569fcb66738a2c68358df0d5ff458f8/Demo/OpenGLView.swift